# Can I host Spree Comerce website on Adobe catalyst?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, adobe, web-hosting, spree, business-catalyst

I have a client who wants Spree E-commerce site (ROR based site ) to be hosted on his Adobe Business Catalyst web hosting. Just wanted to know can it be deployed on Adobe Business Catalyst?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Installing Spree requires database access and the ability to run code on the server. Adobe Catalyst's tag line is:

> "Business Catalyst's hosted solution helps you build powerful business
>   websites, in less time and **without server-side coding**."